# How to implement Bootstrap 4 for Angular 2 ngb-pagination

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I have a `Angular2` app with a `component` where I have a table. 
Table is generated via `*ngFor` directive.
Each row of the `table` is an object with 9 fields that is being loaded from the backend when the component is initialized.
In the app I'm trying to use ng-bootstrap for angular module.
[ng-boorstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home)
In particular I'm trying to implement the `pagination` component.

**Could somebody explain how to put the code so it would render e.g. only 10 rows per page pls?** Or give me a reference where the implementation is done.

What I have done is:

- to put the `NgbModule` reference to my module where I'm declaring my component as well as the `NgbPaginationConfig` module (necessary for using custom pagination)
- put the `ngb-pagination` code in the view of my `component` like this

  ```
  <table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Tracking #</th>
          <th>Brand</th>
          <th>Geography</th>
          <th>Country</th>
          <th>Contract Name</th>
          <th>Project Name</th>
          <th>Status</th>
          <th>$US BMC</th>
          <th>Release #</th>
          <th id="column-last"></th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let item of viewRows "> 
          <td>{{item.trackingNr}}</td>
          <td>{{item.brand}}</td>
          <td>{{item.geo}}</td>
          <td>{{item.country}}</td>
          <td>{{item.contractName}}</td>
          <td>{{item.projectName}}</td>
          <td>{{item.status}}</td>
          <td>{{item.usBmc}}</td>
          <td>{{item.releaseNr}}</td>
          <td id="column-last">
              <span class="awficon-edit" id="row-icons"></span>
              <span class="awficon-close-2" id="row-icons"></span>
          </td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
  ```

[image]

Answer (score 37, accepted):

it's my working solution.
API for ngb-pagination: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/pagination

```
    ...
</table>
<ngb-pagination [collectionSize]="totalItems" [pageSize]="itemsPerPage" [(page)]="page" [maxSize]="7" [rotate]="true" (pageChange)="loadPage($event)"></ngb-pagination>
```

In your component you need some like that. Don't forget set your variable in constructor:

```
  itemsPerPage: number;
  totalItems: any;
  page: any;
  previousPage: any;

  ...
  loadPage(page: number) {
    if (page !== this.previousPage) {
      this.previousPage = page;
      this.loadData();
    }
  }
  ...

  loadData() {
    this.dataService.query({
      page: this.page - 1,
      size: this.itemsPerPage,
    }).subscribe(
      (res: Response) => this.onSuccess(res.json(), res.headers),
      (res: Response) => this.onError(res.json())
      )
  }
```

Comment: The component documentation lacks important details that you have covered. Thank you.

Comment: how are you getting the previous page?  I see the type any.  but am missing where you are assigning a value.

Comment: I get params in routerResolver, for example:
    
    ```resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
            const page = route.queryParams['page'] ? route.queryParams['page'] : '1';
            const sort = route.queryParams['sort'] ? route.queryParams['sort'] : 
    'id,asc';
            return {
                page: page
            };
        }```

Comment: I use it for prevent load current page (if user load 6 page and click on 6, data will reload.So i subscribe to params in constuctor.
    
     
```
this.routeData = this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe((data) => {
            this.page = data['pagingParams'].page;
            this.previousPage = data['pagingParams'].page;
        });
```

Answer (score 9):

I was searching for answers to this same question and nobody seems to post a clear answer.

Here's my solution:

**ngbPagination with ngFor in Angular 7**

```js
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {


currentPage = 1;
itemsPerPage = 5;
pageSize: number;

constructor() { }

  public onPageChange(pageNum: number): void {
    this.pageSize = this.itemsPerPage*(pageNum - 1);
  }
  
  public changePagesize(num: number): void {
  this.itemsPerPage = this.pageSize + num;
}

}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-6 input-group">
        <div class="col-5 input-group-addon">
            <ngb-pagination [collectionSize]="users.length" #numPages [pageSize]="itemsPerPage" [(page)]="currentPage" (pageChange)="onPageChange(currentPage)"></ngb-pagination>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1 input-group-addon">
            <input class="input-sm text-center" type="number" [min]="10" [max]="users.length" step="1" [(ngModel)]="itemsPerPage" (onClick)="changePagesize(pageSize)">
        </div>
    </div>
    <ul *ngIf="users">
        <li *ngFor="let user of users | slice: pageSize | slice: 0:itemsPerPage">
            <img [src]="user.avatar" alt="{{ user.avatar }}">
            <p>{{ user.id }}. {{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <pre><span class="float-md-left">Page: {{ currentPage }} / {{numPages.pageCount}}</span><span class="float-md-right">Found items: {{ itemsPerPage }} / {{ users.length }}</span></pre>
</div>
```

This solution also applies to Angular 6. I have not tested it on other versions.

For more information, check the [documentation](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/pagination/api#NgbPagination). Unfortunatley... it lacks vital information regarding ngFor iteration.

Another problem I had was how to set the number of pages. I decided to add my complete solution for those having the same problem. I found this answer [here](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/682). Take note of the identifier #numPages above. Here is a [live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mquapb?file=app%2Fpagination-advanced.html) on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I found an awesome solution in github.
Check it out.
https://github.com/michaelbromley/ng2-pagination