# Angular 7 variable in view not initialized from url query params on first load

Tags: angular, typescript, url-parameters, angular7

I'm new in Angular and I have problem with pass params from url to view on first load.

In my URL i have parameter page:

.../catalog?page=3

In component I have next code:

```
export class CatalogListComponent implements OnInit {
     page;

     constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute){
     }

     ngOnInit(){
       this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
          this.page = +params['page'] || 1;
        });
     }

     setPage(page: number) {
    this.router.navigate(['catalog'], { queryParams: {...this.queryParams, page } });
  }
}
```

In view I use [ngb-pagination](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/pagination/examples):

```
<ngb-pagination class="pagination"
                              [collectionSize]="items.total"
                              [rotate]="true"
                              [(page)]="page"
                              [maxSize]="5"
                              [pageSize]="20"
                              (pageChange)="setPage(page)"
              >
</ngb-pagination>
```

When I'm open/refresh link in browser .../catalog?page=3 [ngb-pagination](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/pagination/examples) always shows me page **1** instead of **3**, but next navigation works fine([page num in url and in pagination the same).

**What I'm doing wrong ?**

Comment: Try `this.page = +params['page']` to convert the "3" as string to number.

Comment: Try putting it in the constructor instead.

Comment: Hi, Alex K! `onInit()` should be `ngOnInit()`

Comment: Thank for answers, still not working, I updated code examples.

Comment: Can you log the values of `page` and `items`?

Answer (score 0):

As answered before, you should refactor your method with the following code:

```
 ngOnInit(){
       this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
          this.page = params['page'];
        });
     }
```

And there is a little trick to print what you want in the console:

```
console.log('my value is: ', example);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ngb-pagination [collectionSize]="total | async" 
(pageChange)="pageChanged($event)"  
[(page)]="page" aria-label="Pagination"></ngb-pagination>
```

you should use / pass the $event as argument instead of page

Ref : http://plnkr.co/edit/TDm5rv4RmxIKoWYWp8Qa?p=preview

Comment: Seems to be duplicate . Rer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41223400/how-to-implement-bootstrap-4-for-angular-2-ngb-pagination

Answer (score 0):

You should add `*ngIf` directive as attribute to `ngb-pagination`. The code should look like this

```
<ngb-pagination *ngIf="total" [collectionSize]="total"...></ngb-pagination>
```

It worked in my case.